# Proving that the stabilizer of $\{2,4,6\}$ in $D_{6}$ is isomorphic to $S_{3}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

For me $D_{6}$ is the dihedral group of $2n$ elements as on Wikipedia.

the stabilizer of  $\{2,4,6\}$ in $D_{6}$ is defined here [Understanding how reflection acts on rotation in $D_{6}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840637/understanding-how-reflection-acts-on-rotation-in-d-6) which is the following set $\{id. , \rho^{2}, \rho^{4}$, reflection through the axis of symmetry passing through the vertex 2 and between vertices 4 & 6, reflection through the axis of symmetry passing through the vertex 4 and between vertices 2 & 6, reflection through the axis of symmetry passing through the vertex 6 and between vertices 2 & 4 } where $\rho$ means rotation.

**My trial to create a homomorphism is this:**\

$() \rightarrow id., (12) \rightarrow \rho^{2}, (13) \rightarrow \rho^{4}, (23) \rightarrow $ reflection through the axis of symmetry passing through the vertex 2 and between vertices 4 & 6, $(1 2 3) \rightarrow $ reflection through the axis of symmetry passing through the vertex 4 and between vertices 2 & 6 and $(132) \rightarrow $  reflection through the axis of symmetry passing through the vertex 6 and between vertices 2 & 4  .

Is this a correct isomorphism? Is there a smarter way of saying that they are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to construct an explicit isomorphism.

1. Compute the number of elements in the stabilizer. It must be $6$.
2. Prove that the stabilizer is not commutative.
3. Use the fact that there is exactly one non-commutative group of order $6$, the group $S_3$.

Comment: Is there a rigorous way of proving that the stabilizer is non-commutative?

Comment: One approach would be to note that it has subgroups of order $2$ and $3$ by Cauchy's theorem, and then show that you have $\Bbb Z_3\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: @Math: The most rigorous way is to just find two elements there that do not commute. I would take any two reflections in the stabilizer.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your first comment answers which question of mine.