# Operations on subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a nonempty set $S$. Then $G$ also acts on the set of subsets in $S$.

Let $U$ be subset in $S$. Then the stabilizer of $U$ is $$G_{U}=\{ g\in G \mid gU=U\}$$

The author briefly mentioned that $G_{U}$ can be also written as $$G_{U}=\{g\in G \mid gu\in U, \forall u \in U\}$$

I do not quite see this. If $U$ is finite, then these two definition are interchangeable as the map $U\rightarrow U, u\mapsto gu $ is injective and hence also surjective (a injective map from a finite set to itself is also surjective.) But I do not think they are the same thing if $U$ is infinite. (Let $G$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ with addition and let $U=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, then by the second definition $1$ is a stabilizer of $U$, but by the first definition it is not.)

Which one should be the correct definition or did I understand this incorrectly?

I may need this to prove the following result:

$G_{U}=G \Leftrightarrow U$ is a union of $G$ orbits on $U$

Form LHS to RHS is easy, as $G_{U}$ is a subgroup of $G$. We can restrict the group action from $G$ to $G_{U}$ and therefore $G_{U}$ acts on $U$. i.e $U$ is a union of $G_U$ orbits on $U$. If $G_U=G$, then  $U$ is a union of $G$ orbits on $U$.

If I assume the first definition to be true I cannot get the if direction. But if I assume the second definition then things will become much easier.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the example I give the group action is defined to be addition.

Comment: The stabiliser $G_U$ of a set $U$ is defined as follows, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109769/definition-of-stabilizer-of-a-set).

Comment: You are correct, they are not equivalent. The first definition is correct. The second definition does not always define a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's the pointwise stabilizer, not the stabilizer of the set. Unfortunately the definitions are not the same in all of the standard  textbooks. But the OP's second definitino is definitely wrong.

Comment: In my comments in the previous post I was pointing out that usage varies among authors. Personally (with apologies to Wielandt) I find $G_U$ more natural and intuitive for the setwise stabilizer, because $U$ is a set. I often use $G_{(U)}$ for the pointwise stabilizer.

Comment: Thank you for nice reply. Once I remedy the definition for setwise stabilizer, how could I prove the second half of my question? 'If $U$ is a union of orbits of $G$ on $U$, then $G_U =G$'? It might happen that for some $g\in G$, $gU\subsetneq U$.

Comment: Who are you referring to when you say, "the author"? Which book are you talking about?

Comment: I am self studying the lecture notes written by Lothar Göttsche. There is even a lecture video that I can study along with it. You can find his video on youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of this answer let's agree on your first definition, $G_U = \{g \in G : gU = U \}$.

(As noted in comments, your second definition is simply wrong, because it does not define a subgroup, and some authors, including Wielandt in his book on Permutation Groups, use a different definiton $G_U = \{g \in G : \forall u \in U, gu=u \}$.)

The question is, suppose that $U$ is a union of orbits of $G$ on $S$. Prove that $G_U = G$.

So we have to prove that $gU=U$ for all $g \in G$, and to do that we need to prove that $gU \subseteq U$ and $U \subseteq gU$.

Let $u \in U$. Then $gu$ is in the orbit of $G$ on $U$. But, since $U$ is a union of orbits of $G$ on $U$, this orbit must be contained within $U$, and so $gu \in U$. Hence $gU \subseteq U$.

Similarly, we have $g^{-1}u \in U$, so $u \in gU$ and hence $U \subseteq gU$.

Comment: Thank you for your complete proof and patience.