# Stabilizer of a finite subset divides order of subset

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, orbit-stabilizer, stabilizer

Let $G$ be a finite group whose order is divisible by $p^\alpha$ for some prime $p$. Let $X$ be the set of all subsets (not necessarily subgroups) of $G$ whose order is $p^\alpha$. Let $H\in X$, let $1\in H$, and let $G$ act on $X$ by left multiplication. I want to show that $|\text{Stab}_G(H)|$ divides $|H|$.

As far as I understand, for $h\in H$, we have that $\text{Stab}_G(h)$ is the set of all $s\in G$ which fix $h$; i.e. $s\cdot h=h$. Then, $\text{Stab}_G(H)$, intuitively (to me), is the set of all $s\in G$ that fix *all* of $H$; i.e. $s\cdot h=h$ **for all** $h\in H$.

(I will note that according to an answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109769/definition-of-stabilizer-of-a-set), elements of $\text{Stab}_G(H)$ need only permute the elements of $H$? Is this true? Why? In any case, the question I'm trying to solve did not come with a specification.)

I have shown, at the very least, that $\text{Stab}_G(H)\subseteq H$, as $1\in H$ implies that $s\cdot 1 \ (= s)\in H$.

However, if, say, $|G|=p^\alpha n$ for some natural $n$, how can I show that there does not exist a prime $q\neq p$ such that $q\mid n$ and $q\mid |\text{Stab}_G(H)|$?

I've tried using the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem to no avail. I know that the orbits of $H$ partition $H$, but since I don't know how to find out how many orbits of $H$ there are, I don't see how the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem helps.

What should I do?

Comment: $G$ does not act on $H$ by left-multiplication. $G$ acts on $X$ by left-multiplication, $H$ is both a subset of $G$ and an element of $X$, and $\mathrm{Stab}_G(H)$ acts on $H$ by left-multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointwise stabilizer of $\{g\in G\mid gh=h\textrm{ for all }h\in H\}$ of $H$ is the trivial subgroup. This is because groups are cancellative; $gh=h$ for even a single $h$ implies $g=e$. Indeed, the action $G\curvearrowright X$ by left-multiplication defines $gH:=\{gh\mid h\in H\}$, so with respect to this action we must instead be talking about the setwise stabilizer $S=\mathrm{Stab}_G(H)=\{g\in G\mid gH=H\}$.

When a group acts on a set, that set may be partitioned into orbits, and the orbit-stabilizer theorem tells us how to calculate the size of an element's orbit from the size of that element's stabilizer. However, different orbits can have different sizes, and this prevents us from saying much about the group's size or the orbit's size having any sort of divisibility relationship with the set's size.

Things can work out, though. For example, when a group acts on itself by multiplication (the *regular* action), the stabilizers are trivial and the group is its own orbit. Or, if $K<G$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then restricting the regular action $G\curvearrowright G$ to $K\curvearrowright G$ means the whole of $G$ is no longer a single orbit, so there are multiple orbits, but stabilizers are still trivial, so all orbits have the same size. Indeed, the orbits are none other than the right cosets of $K$, i.e. the "orbit space" (collection of orbits) is the right coset space $K\backslash G$.

In this case, we have $S\curvearrowright H$. Even though $H$ is not a group, so $S$ is not a subgroup of it (merely a subset), this is still a free action (stabilizers are trivial, i.e. if $h\in H$ and $s\in\mathrm{Stab}_G(H)$ and $sh=h$, then $s=e$), so all orbits are the same size, and $H$ is a disjoint union of these orbits. Thus, $|H|$ is $|S|$ times the number of orbits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate on "this is still a free action... so all orbits are the same size"? Sorry, but I'm really not able to make the connection between what you said about the regular action of $G$ and the stabilizers being trivial. What is the notation $A\curvearrowright B$? $A$ acting on $B$? In that case, what does it mean for $K\curvearrowright G$? How does this relate to $S\curvearrowright H$, since $S$ and $H$ are both *not* $G$, and how does this show that the orbits are the same size? If you are referring to the setwise stabilizer, why is it trivial?

Comment: @iateawalrus I explicitly said the *pointwise* stabilizer is trivial, and I said why. Yes $\curvearrowright$ means action, I should have mentioned. The action $K\curvearrowright G$ is a restriction of the action of $G\curvearrowright G$ to a subgroup $K\le G$; they are "free" for the same reason. And $S\curvearrowright H$ is a restriction of the action $S\curvearrowright H$ to a subset $H\subseteq G$, which is again free for the same reason. That is, $sh=h$ implies $s=e$, so all stabilizers of $S\curvearrowright H$ are trivial, so (by orbit-stabilizer) all orbits have the same size.

Comment: My middle two paragraphs are just commentary that puts this exercise into perspective with other facts about group actions. Feel free to ignore them if you want to focus on what's relevant to simply solving the exercise.